# Running Spring app as jar, beans not found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, jar

When using eclipse, I get no errors, however once i export my project as a runnable jar file and try running it w/ java -jar myjar.jar, it gives me this error.

```
Jun 05, 2014 1:46:22 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@112f8578: startup date     [Thu Jun 05 13:46:22 CDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 05, 2014 1:46:22 PM     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory     preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@56e3cbb9: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named   'jobTaskService'is defined 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
at com.tw.JobQueue.App.main(App.java:22)
```

But again, when i use Eclipse, this error does not occur.

Here is some of my code

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tw.JobQueue" />
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="emailService" class="com.tw.JobQueue.service.EmailService">
</bean>

<bean id="emailJob" name="EmailJob" class="com.tw.JobQueue.job.EmailJob" scope="prototype">
    <property name="emailService" ref="emailService" />
</bean>

<bean id = "jobWorker" class="com.tw.JobQueue.job.JobWorker" scope="prototype">
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.tw.JobQueue.model.JobLog</value>
            <value>com.tw.JobQueue.model.JobTask</value>
            <value>com.tw.JobQueue.model.JobType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="zacharyphilley@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numThreads = 10;

    if(args.length > 0){
        numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml");

    IJobTaskService jobTaskService = context.getBean("jobTaskService", IJobTaskService.class);
```

JobTaskService.java

```
@Service("jobTaskService")
public class JobTaskService implements IJobTaskService {
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

**********************EDIT SOLVED**********************************************

Turns out that Eclipse's method of creating jars is not very compatible w/ my setup of using maven, hibernate, and spring together. The best option for this setup would be to use the one-jar maven plugin and follow the instructions on their website: 
https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/

This plugin will create jar files that run just like they do in an eclipse maven project.

Regardless, thank you all for your input in trying to help solve my problem.

Comment: Does the jar contain the context file?

Comment: yes, it is in myjar.jar/recources/applicationContext.xml

Comment: Is the class in the correc package `com.tw.JobQueue`?

Comment: all classes in this project are either in com.tw.JobQueue or a package within com.tw.JobQueue (ex. com.tw.JobQueue.dao)

Answer (score 0):

The application context xml should generally be put in the root folder in the package hierarchy. So the packaging structure should look like this.

```
myjar.jar/applicationContext.xml
```

If you wish to put it under resources folder, then refer to it exactly like that.. for e.g.
if applicationContext.xml file is in resources folder, it can be accessed through classpath like this

```
classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in eclipse works fine, but when I export the JAR it gives me this error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type 
[MyBean] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

to solve the problem i had to declare beans

```
<bean id="odiAuxDAO" class="<my_package>.OdiAuxDAO"/>
```

insted of component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.<my_package>" />
```